# SQL - range of dates to Payperiod

Tags: sql, date

Alright all you SQL masters and Jedi's, here is my problem and request for a case statement in SQL SSMS.

I have dates from the year.

So the dates for each row is starting from 03/24/2013 going forward to today.

I want every 14 days to be called 04/12/2013.

```
So from 03/24/2013 thru 04/06/2013 would be all 04/12/2013 and
from 04/07/2013 thru 04/20/2013 would be 04/26/2013 and
from 04/21/2013 thru 05/04/2013 would be 05/10/2013 and so on.
```

Below is a set to give you an idea:

- Date  ------      PayDate
- 3/24/2013 -----     4/12/2013
- 3/25/2013-----   4/12/2013
- 3/26/2013    -----4/12/2013
- 3/27/2013    -----4/12/2013
- 3/28/2013    -----4/12/2013
- 3/29/2013    -----4/12/2013
- 3/30/2013    -----4/12/2013
- 3/31/2013    -----4/12/2013
- 4/1/2013     -----4/12/2013
- 4/2/2013     -----4/12/2013
- 4/3/2013     -----4/12/2013
- 4/4/2013     -----4/12/2013
- 4/5/2013     -----4/12/2013
- 4/6/2013     -----4/12/2013
- 4/7/2013     -----4/26/2013
- 4/8/2013     -----4/26/2013
- 4/9/2013     -----4/26/2013
- 4/10/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/11/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/12/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/13/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/14/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/15/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/16/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/17/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/18/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/19/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/20/2013    -----4/26/2013
- 4/21/2013    -----5/10/2013

Hope this made sense.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me.  I find your entire question unclear.

Comment: is 4/12/2013 the base date?

Comment: @DanBracuk think payroll - he's trying to find the date at which people get payed

Comment: So what I am trying is for dates to be identified as Pay Period. So depending on the date, what Payperiod it would fall under. 4/12/2013 is the PayPeriod date for dates from 3/24/2013 thru 04/06/2013

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this - I would probably want to create a table with all the appropriate pay dates, and then join to that using logic that is the relatively simple.

Something like:

```
select PayDate.date
from date
inner join PayDate on datediff(day, date.date, PayDate.date) > 18 AND datediff(day, date.date, PayDate.date) < 4
```

or something. I haven't worked out the exact `datediff` because I'm in the middle of something, but that should be enough to get started with.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the response. I added this to the Select Statement: case when min(a.StrDate) >= '03/24/2013' then min(a.strdate)+19 end  PayPeriodDate.....................This gave the first date the 04/12/2013 but as the statement is self explanatory, it just adds the dates

Comment: @RahulP Yeah you really need to build that `PayDate` table - you'll want to look at loops for whatever SQL technology you're using. I recommend just generating a big one well into the future and using that, rather than trying to do a fancy calculation in your procedure, but then I'm a Data Warehouse kinda guy...

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the Advise. However, I am more of a Finance/Decision Support with a Read Only access. My SQL knowledge is limited to "Self-Learning." So, creating a new table would be a little out of my league. My IT department is pretty, , well lets say, busy and unhelpful. lol. I am using a huge dB to run queries to create dashboards in Tableau. Now that might be an option, as Tableau is an Analytics system. I am probably gonna try a few more calculations to see if anything works. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

SO taking hints from the Awesome StackOverflow and taking the suggestion from Jeff, I went on to create a Temp Table and got the query to work. I now get the information I need using the below code for Temp table and doing an Inner Join on Dates and including the PP date in the Select and Group By statement.

Hope this helps other people with Read-Only privileges to the Database.

```
   declare @temp  table
   (
   Date datetime,
   PPDate datetime
   )

   INSERT INTO @temp (Date, PPDate)
   SELECT '2013-2-10', '2013-3-1'
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-2-11', '2013-3-1'
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-2-12', '2013-3-1'
   ....
   ....
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-2-23', '2013-3-1'
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-2-24', '2013-3-15'
   ....
   ....
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-3-8', '2013-3-15'
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-3-9', '2013-3-15'
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-3-10', '2013-3-29'
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-3-11', '2013-3-29'
   ....
   ....
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-3-22', '2013-3-29'
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-3-23', '2013-3-29'
   UNION ALL SELECT '2013-3-24', '2013-4-12'

   select a.StrDate, t.PPDate, sum(Qty) Qty from tbl1 a
   Inner Join @temp t on t.date = a.StrDate
   group by a.StrDate, t.PPDate
```